# Android: Override onKeyUp and onKeyDown in Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent, back-button, tabactivity, activitygroup

I have an Android tabbed application that displays music charts (say, ChartActivity), each of which in turn displays a list of music tunes (say, EntryActivity). Tapping on each entry of music tunes will launch, e.g., a YouTube app (default actions). That is, in list.setOnItemClickListener of EntryActivity, I make calls:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(selectedSongUrl));
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("YouTube", intent);
```

(Yes, I use ActivityGroup and TabActivity.)

The problem is that when I tab the back button from the YouTube screen, the active view does not come back to EntryActivity, but to ChartActivity. I guess, this is because I could not override onKeyUp and onKeyDown in YouTube screen so that I can further pass the event to the parent activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

// Overrides the default implementation for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK 
// so that all systems call onBackPressed().
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
        parentActivity.onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Is there any way to let EntryActivity know callback events sent from Intent.ACTION_VIEW?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on the setup of your app... Is this a traditional tabbed activity where each tab displays its own activity (e.g. ChartActivity and EntryActivity are tabs)?

If so, you could do the following in your TabGroupActivity:

1. Override onPause() to save the index of the currently active tab in SharedPreferences.
2. Override onResume() to read in that preference (if it exists) and switch to the tab that you were last in.
3. Override onDestroy() and remove that preference so the next time you launch the activity you start in the correct tab.

If that is not how your activity is set up, please explain a little more about how things are set up.